# Creating and updating audit table

Tags: sql, database

Im currently trying to create an audit table to track users (username) who update the tblSOLINE table and the time that they do an update, However I am having issues with tblSOLINE not taking in any data to see if my audit table is working! Below is the insert statement I am using (even though it says 1 rows effected when I check nothing has changed), the audit table and the triggers code, any ideas as to why this isnt working? any help will be greatly appreciated so thanks in advance! :)

```
CREATE TABLE SOLINEupdates
(
a_user char (10) ,
a_date datetime , 
a_ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SOLINEupdates] PRIMARY KEY(a_id)
)
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_SOLINEupdateuser
ON tblSOLine
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT into SOLINEupdates VALUES (current_user, current_timestamp)
GO
```

---

```
insert into tblSOLine
([SOHeaderID]
,[ProductID]
,[Quantity])
VALUES
(91
,2
,3)
GO
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Post your image here, not the link

Comment: Please post your code IN the question, not screen shots.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to include the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: You defined your trigger as an UPDATE trigger but you are testing this with an INSERT.

Comment: Thank you! still relativity new to this but that solved it